# Getting error code ('wht?') in ExtAudioFileOpenURL in Swift when using aubio to read file

Tags: ios, swift, extaudiofile, aubio

I'm using **aubio** to analyse an audio file, but when I try to use the function new_aubio_source like this:

```
let source = new_aubio_source(StringToUnsafeMutablePointerChar_t(url.absoluteString), 0, 512)
```

I always get these errors.

```
AUBIO ERROR: source_apple_audio: Failed opening file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C11B42E5-02B5-4373-8302-0728B2CB2296/Documents/music.m4a, error in ExtAudioFileOpenURL ('wht?')
AUBIO ERROR: source_wavread: Failed opening file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C11B42E5-02B5-4373-8302-0728B2CB2296/Documents/music.m4a (System error: No such file or directory)
AUBIO ERROR: source: failed creating aubio source with file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C11B42E5-02B5-4373-8302-0728B2CB2296/Documents/music.m4a at samplerate 0 with hop_size 512
```

I am 100% sure that the path is correct, but I just can't find out why these errors occur. I think the problem is in the first error message (source_apple_audio).

source_apple_audio is defined here:

[source_apple_audio](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/blob/master/src/io/source_apple_audio.c)

which used this function: ExtAudioFileOpenURL, and got the error code ('wht?')

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Although the question is quite old, the path of a file system url is `url.path` rather than `url.absoluteString`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you also have this problem when removing the leading `file://` ?

Please [open a new issue](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/issues/new).

Comment: Yes, THIS is the solution!

Comment: For me, this was done by swapping `let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)` for `let fileURL = URL(string: filePath)`